# The roots of my equation are real numbers but the discriminant says otherwise

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$X^2-49=0$$

$$X^2=49$$

$$\sqrt{X}= ± \sqrt{49}$$

$$X=±7$$

Discriminant:
$$B^2-4ac$$

$$A=1$$

$$B=0$$

$$C=49$$

$$(0)^2-4(1)(49)$$
$$0-196=(-196)$$

A negative discriminant means that the roots of the equation is not real, but as I have shown, the solution is clearly $±7$ which are both real and equal, and would mean that the discriminant should be equal to 0 as well.

Please help me. And God Bless

Comment: When you string all your equations together with no separators it becomes unreadable.  In any case, if your quadratic is $x^2-49$ then the discriminant is $0^2-4\times 1 \times (-49)=4\times 49>0$.

Comment: $c=-49$, not $49$

Comment: "which are both real and equal": in my country, $-7$ and $+7$ are distinct.

Comment: Yves Daoust, yes you are right, and thank you for your insight with the problem I presented. I simply forgot to put "in their absolute values", but nonetheless, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $c = -49$, so $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 0^2 + 4(1)(49) = \boxed{196}$

Answer (score 2):

The equation is

$$1\cdot x^2+0\cdot x+(-49)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If the quadratic equation is given  by $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ then, $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
The discriminant is $D=\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$

The equation in your question can be re-written as: $$x^2+0.x+(-49)=0$$

On comparing the coefficients of the terms, you'll get where you went wrong while finding the determinant.

Comment: Thank You for all of you, It was really late here yesternight thus I couldn't keep focused anymore, and simply decided to ask much knowledgeable persons(all of you) for help. It is fully appreciated your efforts and prudence. Again Thank You and God Bless.